# UINavigationBar does not position correctly on 4" or 3.5"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6, iphone-5

I'm having a really hard time making my application work with the new iPhone 5's screen.  I can have the layout all set up for the 3.5" screen but when I change it to the 4" everything moves around and then it affects the 3.5".  But my biggest issue is my navigation bar moves to the bottom on the screen every time I change the size.

I am using AutoLayout although I'd prefer not to, so I can allow iOS5 users to use my app.

This is what I mean:[image: UINavigationBar moves to bottom]

The Navigation bar constraints are:

- **Top, Right, and Left:** Superview.
- **Bottom:** Top of the UIImageView below it.

Comment: What do you mean by "change the size". Do you mean changing the size of the controller in IB? I've tried this, and I can't duplicate your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, by changing the size I meant changing the size of the UIViewController.  However, for this one view in particular it's in a separate .xib file.  If I change the VC size in the main storyboard it works just fine.

Comment: Were you able to learn any more about this issue. I turned off autolayout in a storyboard screen that was using it before, and how if I put a uinavigationbar at the top of an iPad Storyboard screen it gets placed at the bottom at runtime. If I put it just 1 pixel down from the top, then it stays where it should be.